# react-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1)

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

When I try to run ionic serve it crashes and I can't serve my Ionic project. Here is the text in the console that appears.

```
> react-scripts.cmd start
[react-scripts] Could not find a required file.
[react-scripts]   Name: index.html
[react-scripts]   Searched in: C:\Users\Zoran\Desktop\andrej\instagram-copy\public

[ERROR] react-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Comment: Kindly share your project files image and `package.json` code